# How do I turn off autogeneration of sitemap.xml in ASP.NET Core Razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Long time developer, but not into SEO. I've been diving into sitemaps.  I'm using ASP.NET Core Razor pages.

I have a route defined for `server/Index/tag`, where `Index` is my `Index.cshtml` file and a tag is just a parameter I am passing in from my database. I would like to create a `sitemap.xml` page that is autogenerated out of my database, seems logical.

However, when I try that, I get this autogenerated `sitemap.xml` page that has listed a bunch of the actual pages in my site, which is not what I want. It lists pages in the site but adds this:

```
<!--  created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com  -->
```

Ok, so this seems to be something coming from Visual Studio 2022 (.NET 8). How the heck do I turn this thing off?

I've got a `sitemap.cshtml` file defined as:

```
@page "/sitemap.xml"
@model sitemapModel

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

@{
    var server = "https://servername.com";
    
    Layout = null;
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    await Response.WriteAsync("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>");
}

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    @foreach (var tag in Model.Tags)
    {
        <url>
            <loc>@($"{server}/Index/{tag}")</loc>
            <lastmod>@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</lastmod>
        </url>
    }
</urlset>
```

This page never seems to be called. If I go to `/sitemap.xml`, I get redirected to `Index/sitemap.xml`, which is not what I am looking for.  What am I missing here?  TIA.

Wally

Comment: try using controllers this way `[Route("/sitemap.xml")]
public class SitemapController : Controller` then your code goes here `[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()`

Comment: @kyenry Thanks but I am in razor pages, not mvc.  I've done what I think is the razor way by having page "/sitemap.xml"  I've also added builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/sitemap", "Sitemap.xml");
});

Unfortunately, I am not getting any love on getting this to work.

Comment: Could you pls share the steps for how to autogenerated the sitemap.xml?  For the routing, It works fine without configuring the RazorPagesOptions, i just define the `@page "/sitemap.xml" `. Where is your sitemap.cshtml location?

Comment: @Rena I don't know where this autogenerated sitemap.xml file is coming from.  I didn't do anything that I am aware of to generate the file.  i just created an asp .net web project a while back.  I've been working with it for a while.

Comment: I looked at the sitemap.xml file in a little more detail.  The pages have my azure web sites dot net server name in them.  Does azure do something when you add a publishing profile?

Comment: Found it!  Somehow, I must have created a sitemap.xml file in the wwwroot directly.  I removed that file, and then I started to get my razor page being called.  Thank you to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

I Put your exact code in my project, and everything works fine!
here is the image (just remove your tag from foreach and replace with for loop)
[image]

I'm suspecting that you build `razor view` instead of `razor page empty`.
so far with your explanations, your problem is from somewhere else.

let me know if it helped or not. if not, give us more info.

Comment: Thank you for your post, see a comment above for the resolution.  :-)